# Groups for which the $n$-power map is a homomorphism

Tags: gr.group-theory

Let $\mathcal{V}_n$ be the collection of all groups satisfying $(ab)^n=a^nb^n$ for all $a,b$.

In particular $\mathcal{V}_1$ consists of all groups and $\mathcal{V}_2$ consists of all abelian groups, and is contained in $\mathcal{V}_n$ for all $n$.

> For which coprime integers $n,m$ is $\mathcal{V}_n\cap\mathcal{V}_m$ reduced to abelian groups?

Comment: If $n=m=1$, certainly not. If $n=2$ or $m=2$, clearly yes. Could you give a little more background? Have you checked when $n=1$?

Comment: If n=3 and m=5, then G is an abelian group.

Comment: m and n two positive integer bigger than 1.

Comment: It seems obvious to me (although I did not downvote). Hint: if I choose n to be the order of the (finite) group, what is a bad choice for m? Gerhard "Maybe I Shouldn't Give Hints" Paseman, 2017.10.23.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman Yes, ok, it's obvious that it's false for some values of $(m,n)$, such as $(kn\pm 1,n)$ whenever there exists a non-abelian group of order $n$, e.g., $(6,7)$. This does not mean that the question is obvious for every value of $(m,n)$. I'll edit to make the question more interesting (and also change the title "How to find a simple proof for a group to be abelian?" which is a poor choice).

Comment: Actually I'm curious whether $\mathcal{V}_3$ consists of solvable groups.

Comment: Herstein had as an exercise that groups belonging to three classes (n,n+1,n+2) were abelian, and this was subsequently generalized to other integer triples.  I imagine pairs leading to abelian groups were classified as well.  Gerhard "Sorry, Doesn't Recall The References" Paseman, 2017.10.23.

Comment: In my previous comment I'm mistaken: I should have said "$(kn+1,n)$ for every $n\ge 3$", since on the one hand $kn-1$ is not correct, and since on the other hand it is enough to start with a non-abelian group of exponent $n$. So to repeat correctly: for every $n\ge 3$ and every $k\ge 0$, $(kn+1,n)$ is a pair for which there is a non-abelian group (in $\mathcal{V}_{kn+1}\cap\mathcal{V}_n$), and even a finite non-abelian group.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman For a good time, you can assume the group is torsion-free.

Comment: Groups for which $(ab)^n = a^nb^n$ are called "$n$-abelian". The set of all $n$ for which $(xy)^n=x^ny^n$ for a given group $G$ is called the "exponent semigroup of $G$. Both F.W. Levi and L-C Kappe have characterized the possible semigroups that can occur as exponent semigroups of a group, and your questions is equivalent to asking when is it the case that $n,m$ both in the semigroup, $\gcd(n,m)=1$, implies the semigroup is all of the integers.

Comment: @YCor: I think that is true. There is a theorem of Alperin which says that every group in $\mathcal{V}_n$ is a section of a direct product of groups where each factor is either abelian, of exponent $n$, or of exponent $n-1$. So to see that groups in $\mathcal{V}_3$ are solvable, you just need to show that groups of exponent $3$ are solvable. It is known that groups of exponent $3$ are nilpotent of class at most three. For references, in the literature groups in $\mathcal{V}_n$ are called $n$-abelian.

Comment: Kappe's paper is called "On $n$-Levi Groups", Arxiv der Mathematik **47** no. 3 (1986) pp 198-210, MR0861866.

Comment: Thanks for these comments, Arturo and spin, and especially for the terminology, which can help finding references (I never heard of these group varieties). Arturo, I was initially confused by your claim that it's a semigroup until I realized you mean a multiplicative semigroup. By the way, the restriction to positive $n,m$ is somewhat artificial, it makes sense to also consider negative integers.

Comment: @YCor: Though you can consider negative numbers, you don't gain much: if $G$ is $n$-abelian, then it is also $(1-n)$-abelian, $(xy)^{1-n} = x(yx)^{-n}y = x(y^nx^n)^{-1}y = xx^{-n}y^{-n}y = x^{1-n}y^{1-n}$. So $\mathcal{V}_n = \mathcal{V}_{1-n}$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin right, but including negative numbers seems to be necessary in the axioms of Levi system you mentioned.

Answer (score 28):

I assume $m,n>1$.

(Edited for readability)

A group is said to be "$n$-abelian" if $(xy)^n=x^ny^n$ for all $x,y\in G$. Following the question, let $\mathcal{V}_n$ denote the variety of all $n$-abelian groups, and let $\mathcal{A}b$ denote the variety of all abelian groups.

The structure of $n$-abelian groups was determined by Alperin: they are the homomorphic images of subgroups of direct products of an abelian group, a group of exponent $n$, and a group of exponent $n-1$.

On the other hand, given a group $G$ we define the "exponent semigroup of $G$" to be
$$\mathcal{E}(G) = \{n\in\mathbb{Z}\mid (xy)^n=x^ny^n\text{ for all }x,y\in G\}.$$
This is a multiplicative semigroup of the semigroup of integers under multiplication. Its structure was determined by F.W. Levi, and also by Luise-Charlotte Kappe. The latter also explored the related concepts of $n$-Levi groups (groups for which $[x^n,y]=[x,y]^n$ for all $x,y\in G$) and $n$-Bell groups (groups for which $[x^n,y]=[x,y^n]$ for all $x,y\in G$). The structure of the semigroup of $n$s for which a given $G$ is an $n$-Levi (resp. an $n$-Bell) group is the same as for the exponent semigroup.

Kappe defines a *Levi system* to be a subset of the integers that satisfies the following five conditions:

1. $n,m\in W$ implies $nm\in W$.
2. $n\in W$ implies $1-n\in W$.
3. $0\in W$.
4. There exists $w\in W$, $w\gt 0$, such that for all $n\in W$, $n^2\equiv n\pmod{w}$ and every integer congruent to $n$ modulo $w$ is in $W$.
5. If the congruence classes of both $n$ and $n+1$ modulo $w$ lie in $W$, then $n\equiv 0\pmod{w}$.

Kappe proves that a subset of the integers is $\mathcal{E}(G)$ for some $G$ if and only if it is $\{0,1\}$, or is a Levi system.

We can drop $\gcd(m,n)=1$ from the hypotheses. The answer to the question is:

> **Theorem.** Let $m,n>1$. Then $\mathcal{V}_n\cap\mathcal{V}_m=\mathcal{A}b$ if and only if $\gcd(n^2-n,m^2-m)=2$.

Note that $2$ divides $n(n-1)$ and $m(m-1)$, so the gcd is at least two.

*Proof.* If $p>2$ is an odd prime that divides $\gcd(n^2-n,m^2-m)$, then a nonabelian group of exponent $p$ is both $n$-abelian and $m$-abelian. Similarly, if $4$ divides $\gcd(n^2-n,m^2-m)$, then a nonabelian group of exponent $4$ is both $n$-abelian and $m$-abelian (since $2$ will divide either $n$ or $n-1$, but not both, and likewise $m$ or $m-1$, but not both). So the condition is necessary.

Conversely, assume $\gcd(n^2-n,m^2-m)=2$, and let $G\in\mathcal{V}_n\cap\mathcal{V}_m$. Then $n,m\in\mathcal{E}(G)$, so the latter is not just $\{0,1\}$, and hence must be a Levi system. Let $w$ be the positive integer guaranteed by property 4. Then $n^2\equiv n\pmod{w}$ and $m^2\equiv m\pmod{w}$, hence $w=1$ or $w=2$.

If $w=1$, then because $n\equiv k\pmod{1}$ for all $k$, it follows that $\mathcal{E}(G)=\mathbb{Z}$, so $G$ is abelian. If $w=2$, then $2\in\mathcal{E}(G)$, so $G$ satisfies $(xy)^2=x^2y^2$, a condition well known to imply that $G$ is abelian. Thus, $G\in\mathcal{A}b$ in either case. $\Box$

I note that Theorem 2 in Kappe's paper also gives this result. Given a subset $T$ of integers that includes $0$ and $1$, and such that if $m,n\in T$ then $k(n^2-n)+m\in T$ for all integers $k$, the theorem provides several conditions equivalent to $T=\mathbb{Z}$. One of them is the existence of a subset $U$ of $T$ such that $\gcd(n^2-n\mid n\in U)=2$. Since $\mathcal{E}(G)$ always satisfies these conditions, it follows that $m,n\in\mathcal{E}(G)$ and $\gcd(m^2-m,n^2-n)=2$ implies $\mathcal{E}(G)=\mathbb{Z}$, and hence $G$ is abelian.

**References.**

- Alperin, J.L. *[A classification of n-abelian groups](https://dx.doi.org/10.4153/CJM-1969-136-1).*
  Canad. J. Math. 21 1969 1238–1244. [MR0248204](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=248204) (40 #1458)
- Kappe , L.C. *[On n-Levi groups](https://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01191994).* Arch. Math. (Basel) 47 (1986), no. 3, 198–210. [MR0861866](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=861866) (88a:20048)
- Levi, F.W.  *Notes on group theory. VII. The idempotent residue classes and the mappings $\{m\}$.* J. Indian Math. Soc. (N. S.) 9, (1945). 37–42. [MR0016414](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=16414) (8,13d)

Comment: $n=4$, $m=14$ would be an example with $\gcd(n,m)>1$ and $\mathcal{V}_n\cap\mathcal{V}_m = \mathcal{A}b$.

Answer (score 7):

A random fact: if $a\to a^3$ is an *automorphism* (for example, if $G$ is finite with order not divisible by $3$) then $G$ is abelian.

If $a\to a^{n+1}$ is an automorphism, then the set of $k$ such that $a\to a^k$ is an endomorphism is a union of conjugacy classes mod $n,$ including the $0$ and $1$ classes.

For powerful $p$-groups, there are plenty of relatively prime pairs one can construct.

Finally, Alperin shows that an $n$-abelian group is a homomorphic image of a subgroup of a direct product of an Abelian group, a group of exponent $n$ and a group of exponent dividing $n-1.$  In particular, a torsion-free such group is abelian (unless I understand the result), and if $m, n$ as in the OP are relatively prime *and* $n-1$ and $m-1$ are relatively prime, then the group is Abelian.

References:

*Trotter, H.F.*, [**Groups in which raising to a power is an automorphism**](http://dx.doi.org/10.4153/CMB-1965-063-4), Can. Math. Bull. 8, 825-827 (1965). [ZBL0135.05101](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0135.05101).

*Moravec, Primož*, [**Schur multipliers and power endomorphisms of groups.**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jalgebra.2006.06.035), J. Algebra 308, No. 1, 12-25 (2007). [ZBL1120.20034](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1120.20034).

*Alperin, J.L.*, [**A classification of $n$-abelian groups**](http://dx.doi.org/10.4153/CJM-1969-136-1), Can. J. Math. 21, 1238-1244 (1969). [ZBL0213.29901](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0213.29901).

Answer (score 6):

Here is an exercise I sometimes give to my first-year graduate students in algebra as a challenge problem.

Let $\varepsilon_n$ be the identity $(xy)^n=x^ny^n$. Show that a set of identities of the form $\{\varepsilon_{n_i}\;|\;i\in I\}$ entails the identity $xy=yx$ iff 
$$
\gcd\left\{\binom{n_i}{2}\;\bigg|\;i\in I\right\} = 1.
$$

The first student who gave a fully correct solution was David Wayne, in 2008. (He is now a data scientist in Boston.)

Comment: That seems to follow immediately from the Alperin result I cite.